# send a file to client

Tags: php, download, client, text-files

I want to write a text file in  the server through Php, and have the client to download that file.

How would i do that?

Essentially the client should be able to download the file from the server.

Answer (score 18):

This is the best way to do it, supposing you don't want the user to see the real URL of the file.

```
<?php
  $filename="download.txt";
  header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
  readfile($filename);
?>
```

Additionally, you could protect your files with mod_access.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the data already posted, there is a header you might want to try.

Its only a *suggestion* to how its meant to be handled, and the user agent can chose to ignore it, and simply display the file in the window if it knows how:

```
<?php

 header('Content-Type: text/plain');         # its a text file
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment');  # hit to trigger external mechanisms instead of inbuilt
```

See [Rfc2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) for more on the Content-Disposition header.

Comment: I didn't know about "Content-Disposition." Thanks for the info. +1

Answer (score 5):

PHP has a number of very simplistic, C-like functions for writing to files. Here is an easy example:

```
<?php
// first parameter is the filename
//second parameter is the modifier: r=read, w=write, a=append
$handle = fopen("logs/thisFile.txt", "w");

$myContent = "This is my awesome string!";

// actually write the file contents
fwrite($handle, $myContent);

// close the file pointer
fclose($handle);
?>
```

It's a very basic example, but you can find more references to this sort of operation here:

[PHP fopen](http://us.php.net/fopen)

Answer (score 3):

If you set the content type to application/octet-stream, the browser will ALWAYS offer file as a download, and will never attempt to display it internally, no matter what type of file it is.

```
<?php
  filename="download.txt";
  header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");

  // output file content here
?>
```

Comment: PS: although it might work with the little d on some UA's, its *not* the RFC spec so you're best to use the upper-case version.

Comment: the other problem with relying on octet-stream, is you force the user to save it, because it cant use MIME to determine what application to open it with externally, and that's a problem.

Comment: @Kent Fredric: According to RFC, the header names are case-insensitive.

Comment: @Kent Fredric: Forcing the user to save instead of open an external app was kind of the point.

Comment: @tylerl yeah, but in this specific case, the OP is actually trying to open notepad with a predetermined string, but you probably wouldn't have know that without seeing their prior post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736942/opening-notepad-exe-with-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Just post a link on the site to http://example.com/textfile.php

And in that PHP file you put the following code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
print "The output text";
?>
```

That way you can create the content dynamic (from a database)...
Try to Google to oter "Content-Type" if this one is not the one you are looking for.

Comment: The link is broken. Could you fix it?

Comment: It's an example link.