# PHP write to file

Tags: php, file

below is some code I am using to "translate" a map array into SQL code so I can easily update my database when I have updated my game map. As you can see it prints out the SQL code onto the screen so I can copy and paste it.

As my maps will get bigger this will become inefficient as it will crash the browser due to mass output, so instead I am wondering if it is possible to make it create a .txt file and write all of the data to it instead of printing onto the screen?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['code'])){
$map = $_POST['code'];
$map = preg_replace("/,\\s*}/i", "}", $map);
$map = str_replace("{", "[", $map);
$map = str_replace("}", "]", $map);
$map = json_decode('[' . $map . ']');

$arrayCount1 = 0;
$arrayCount2 = -1;

$H = sprintf('%05d', 00000);
$V = sprintf('%05d', 00000);
$id = 1;

echo "INSERT INTO `map` (`id`, `horizontal`, `verticle`, `image`) VALUES" . "<br />";

for ($count1 = 0; $count1 < sizeof($map[0]); $count1++){
$arrayCount2++;
$arrayCount1 = 0;
$V = sprintf('%05d', $V + 1);
$H = sprintf('%05d', 00000);

for ($count2 = 0; $count2 < sizeof($map); $count2++){
echo "(" . $id . ", '" . $H . "', '" . $V . "', '" . $map[$arrayCount1][$arrayCount2] . "')," . "<br />";
$arrayCount1++;
$id++;
$H = sprintf('%05d', $H + 1);
}
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That should be quite simple. Add

```
// second parameter 'a' stands for APPEND
$f = fopen('/path/to/the/file/you/want/to/write/to', 'a');
```

to the beginning of your script.

Add

```
fclose($f);
```

to the end fo your script to cleanly close the file handle (good pratice even though handles would be closed the the terminating script automatically).

And the change all your `echo`'s and `print`s to

```
fwrite($f, '<<your string>>');
```

**EDIT:**

That way you can even compress the data on the fly using a [compression stream wrapper](http://de.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php) if amnount of data gets really large.

Answer (score 8):

There is an even simpler approach:

```
ob_start();
# Your code here ...
file_put_contents('yourfile.txt', ob_get_clean());
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is something you plan on writing on a regular interval or by different scripts, look at using flock() to lock the file and prevent data corruption.

```
    $fp = fopen("/tmp/lock.txt", "w+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) { // do an exclusive lock
    fwrite($fp, "Write something here\n");
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // release the lock
} else {
    echo "Couldn't lock the file !";
}

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = <<<your string comes here>>>
if( $fh = @fopen( "myfile.txt", "a+" ) ) {
            fputs( $fh, $str, strlen($str) );
            fclose( $fh );
}
```

this should do...

Comment: note that there are three other similar answers here... ob_start and fwrite goes in the category "stream to file" while this is "push to file" all at once, thus better for dumping. the "lock" answer is the safest one, tho, but most likely overkill for most situations. something like this should be the preferable one, if you see it like that.

Answer (score 1):

write all the lines and then send the file to the client.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737045/send-a-file-to-client) post for further instructions

Answer (score 1):

+my 2 cents:

You may check your database servers mass data loading features, as most of them can load files in batch faster than performing thousands of inserts.

Comment: definetly! the question (from the title) indeed is already answered by others here. but to the OP actual issue it might be better to get another approach. dumping a TXT file because it's too big for the browser may not be the best one.