# Open Download Dialog with PHP

Tags: php, download

I am trying to make an online kickstart config file creator. After the file is created on the server how do I get the download dialog to pop up so the user can download it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Content-Disposition header..

```
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 5):

the magic is in the content-disposition

[send a file to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737045/send-a-file-to-client)