# How to make files ONLY downloadable, not readable by client

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm working on a php script where users can upload any type of file they want, even php files.

All files are uploaded/moved in a specific folder ("uploads").

I don't want these files to be readable otherwise it can cause a major security bug as users can write any php code and take control of my server.

I want these files only to be downloadable by the user client (browser). Like Dropbox for example.

Comment: This might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968106/generate-download-file-link-in-php

Comment: Store the files in a folder that is not web accessible, serve the files using the `Content-Disposition` header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Download Dialog with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985083/open-download-dialog-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

you can deny acces to uploads/move, then force a redirect from all URLS under uploaded/moved to a PHP script

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/uploads/move/(.*)$ /serve_file.php?filePath=$1 [L]
```

then send a force download header like so for example:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($File) . "\"");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filePath));
header("Connection: close");
readfile($filepath);
exit;
```

!!Make sure the $filePath is in uploads/move and not anywhere else or they could grab other files)!!

Thanks @Mark Baker for the optimisation, using readfile is a better way!

Comment: `readfile("uploads/move/".$filePath);` is a lot more efficient than reading the content into memory and then echoing it

Comment: true, what @Mark Baker said :), I'll update the answer